# On click of link open different page and reach to an inline link on that page

Tags: html

I have page1.html and page2.html. There are bunch of inline links on page2.html, on click of each link, page2 scrolls down to certain section on the screen.

Now, I need, on click of certain link on page1.html, page2.html should open and move page to certain section on the screen.

Which could also mean that on click of page1.html link, I am landing on page2.html and automatically some inline got clicked, which scrolled down my page to certain section on page2.html

Please can anyone help me in this.

Comment: use the url fragments, eg page2.html#section-1 will scroll down to element with id="section-1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick example...

If you have a link, i.e. http://www.example.com/page2.html#position1

This will navigate to page2.html, and if you have an html element on the page with id="position1" , it will also scroll down to that specific element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `#` tag to set the id of the element you wish to scroll to.

E.g:
`page2.html#blue` will scroll down to the element with `id="blue"`

Answer (score 0):

scibuff is right, if you use url framents like page2.html#elementIdHere. The browser will open page2.html and scroll to the elment with id elementIdHere.